# Is there a way to speed up the way Mac responds to my trackpad clicks?

Tags: mac, trackpad

I'm new to Mac and Xcode. I realize there's always a significant delay when I click the trackpad and when Mac responds to my action, around 300-500 ms or so, which is very annoying for me. I'm using a new MacBook Pro with plenty of memory and processing power.

Is it a "feature" of Mac? How can I turn if off?

EDIT: OK, I think it has something to do with the "tap to click" feature which I'm currently using. If I press to click, there's no such delay. Anyone has any idea how to fix then?

Comment: Not a programming question...

Comment: I've heard some good things about [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/). This *may* have an option that you can configure. I believe it's now available through the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have trackpad dragging enabled?  If so, it has to wait a moment after you tap in case you tap again and turn the action into a drag -- until then, it can't tell if you want to just click, or click-hold-drag.  The only way to eliminate this delay is to turn off trackpad dragging, so there's no ambiguity about what it should do when you tap.

Comment: yes, that's the reason of why it's being slow. But is there anyway to improve? Is there a tweak somewhere to decrease the dragging wait time? I like this feature and don't want to move things around using more than 1 fingers! As far as I remember, it did not behave like this on a PC laptop..

Answer (score -1):

1. Goto System Preferences > Trackpad
2. Change the Tracking Speed, Double-Click speed and scrolling speed as necessary.

Comment: I think that's the speed that you need to click at in order for it to register.

Comment: The double-click speed (=timeframe within 2 clicks must occur to be interpreted as a double click rather than two consecutive single clicks) seems to have no effect on the "tap to drag and drop" delay. The "tap to drag and drop" timeout is either hard coded or at best within a hidden or undocumented setting.